# Why is subprocess.check_output printing when I don't ask it to?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

Long story short, working with the Pi, if the device is already in use, I kill the process. That all works fine.

The way I am figuring out which process is actually using it is by grabbing the info like so

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "fuser", "/dev/ttyAMA0"])
```

This works fine, I regex my pattern, find my pid and kill it. No problem. I realize I could just add '-k', but I don't want to kill the other process that's actually running in the background trying to access it. It does however print. I don't want it to do that. Moreover, I'd also like to know why it does. The other commands I call in this fashion do not.

Comment: Well I am guessing it prints an output because that appears the be exactly what it [is programmed to do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). The Python docs clearly state that subprocess.check_output() is meant to `Run command with arguments and return its output.` Not sure why your other commands aren't printing though.. quick guess on how to silence the output might be `out = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "fuser", "/dev/ttyAMA0"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.

Comment: @SB87: That worked a charm. Thank you. Legend.